# Wordpress...I want my user to see the homepage of my site, not their profile page when they login to my site

Tags: wordpress

So, I have figured out how to allow people to become subscribers on my site.  Great.  I became a subscriber myself using a different name and email address.  I created a new user name and a new password for myself.  Easy.  Problem is, when I use the user name and password to login I am taken to my new profile page.  I don't want this.  I want any of my potential subscribers to be remain on the same page but be logged in.

This is all Wordpress.

Well, I am very new to codding.  This is the code that I have.  (I did not write it.)  where am I supposed to add the code you gave me?

```
<?php

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 640;

if ( ! function_exists( 'cleanblack_theme_setup' ) ) :
function cleanblack_theme_setup() {
load_theme_textdomain( 'cleanblack', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
$defaults = array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'random-default'         => false,
    'width'                  => 960,
    'height'                 => 150,
    'flex-height'            => false,
    'flex-width'             => false,
    'header-text'            => false,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );


register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'cleanblack Primary Menu', 'cleanblack' )
    ) );
}
endif;
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cleanblack_theme_setup');

function cleanblack_widgets_init() {
            register_sidebar(array('name'=>'Sidebar Top',
                       'before_title' => '<div class="headingred">',
                       'after_title' => '</div>')
            );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'cleanblack_widgets_init' );


function cleanblack_wp_title( $title ) {
    global $page, $paged;

    if ( is_feed() )
        return $title;

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );

    $cleanblack_title = $title . get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    $cleanblack_title .= ( ! empty( $site_description ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) ? ' | ' . $site_description: '';
    $cleanblack_title .= ( 2 <= $paged || 2 <= $page ) ? ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s' ), max( $paged, $page ) ) : '';

    return $cleanblack_title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'cleanblack_wp_title' );

function cleanblack_remove_shortcode($content) {
  if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search()) {
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'cleanblack_remove_shortcode');


function cleanblack_content_limit($max_char, $more_link_text = '(more...)', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);

   if (strlen(isset($_GET['p'])) > 0) {
     echo "<p>";
     echo $content;
     echo "[...]";
     echo "</p>";
   }
   else if ((strlen($content)>$max_char) && ($espacio = strpos($content, " ", $max_char ))) {
     $content = substr($content, 0, $espacio);
     echo $content; 
     echo "[...]";
   }
   else {
     echo $content;
     echo "[...]";
    }
}

include 'theme-options.php';

function cleanblack_scripts() {
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cleanblack_scripts' );


function cleanblack_get_options($atts) {
    $options_array = get_option("cleanblack_options");  
    return esc_attr($options_array[$atts]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function login_redirect_custom() {
  return '/whatever-url-u-want';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', ' login_redirect_custom');
```

in `functions.php`

Comment: OK, I tried that.  Everything now works exactly as it had been working before.  However, I now see this message above the WordPress login box.                   Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ' login_redirect_custom' not found or invalid function name in D:\Hosting\11090154\html\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 199

Comment: check your syntax , or just copy and paste from above . this error means either A - you have a typo - B - You placed the code at the wrong place ..